# Objects memory re-location?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, .net-4.0, clr

Is there any way to *tell* .net runtime , *not* to  re-locate object in memory ?

IMHO - Object can be re-locate by `GC` when  :

- Moving from one generation to another
- Being moved from `finilization-queue` to the `f-reachable` queue.
- else ( *maybe optimization mechanism ?*).

  Also,I thought  immutable (strings)are automatically recreated each time , so they  must be created in a new location.

*(just a theoratical question  )*

Comment: What would be the point of this? In *regular* c#, the object location is an implementation detail that is unavailbe to us.... What are you trying to *do*?

Comment: Immutable objects are not 'recreated' and immutability doesn't affect whether an object will be relocated.

Comment: @MarcGravell  Just learning my friend , just learning.

Comment: @lee If i have stirng `s="1";` and then I write `s="2"` , so `s` is being assigned a new value in a different memory location.

Comment: @RoyiNamir But that has nothing to do with immutability. For example, `a=new int[1];` followed by `a=new int[1];` also assigns a new value with (most likely) different memory location, but arrays are not immutable.

Comment: @Royi yes, but you wouldn't *want* to overwrite the old location; other reference could be pointing to it. If you overwrote it in-place, you would unexpectedly change what those other references are referring to,

Comment: @RoyiNamir - `s` is a reference not an object. A new string "2" will be allocated, and the old string "1" previously pointed to by `s` will remain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As an implementation detail*, the .Net framework can move an object in the memory in the final stage of garbage collection. But this doesn't necessarily mean moving between generations: when performing generation 2 GC, objects in gen 2 will be moved, even though they don't change generation (because there is nowhere to go beyond gen 2).

The finalization queue and the f-reachable queue have nothing to do with this, they contain only references to objects, not the objects themselves.

I have no idea what does this have to do with immutable objects. The runtime doesn't give any special treatment to them (except for strings).

Telling the runtime not to relocate an object (also known as “pinning” the object) is an unusual requirement and should have a really good reason, because it can negatively affect the performance of the GC. To temporarily pin an object in unsafe code, you can use [the `fixed` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx). To do it permanently or from safe code, you can use [`GCHandle.Alloc()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1246yz8f), specifying `GCHandleType.Pinned`.

Comment: you right , I was wrong thinking objects are moved from 1 queue to another , the _pointer_ is removed. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: svick what about the fact that there are 2 HEAPS ( 1 for big objects and the other for smaller) ? Does object can be moved from one to another ( if modified) ?

Comment: The size of an object can never change, so moving to/from the large object heap doesn't make much sense and doesn't happen. And one of the reasons why LOH is useful is that objects in there are not moved (although you shouldn't rely on that and use pinning on large objects too).

Comment: Large object : (larger regerence) or (consume more memory)?

Comment: I don't understand, the size of a reference is constant (4 or 8 bytes). Large objects pretty much mean only arrays that are larger than 85 000 bytes.

Comment: Also, there may be more than 2 heaps: with server GC, there is a small object heap and a large object heap for each CPU. AFAIK, objects never move between heaps.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14241/discussion-between-svick-and-royi-namir)

Answer (score 1):

Pinned Objects tells the gc to not to move it to create large chuck of free space. They are created using [Fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword.

**Useful scenario**

lets think of a scenario where we have an int of array needed to be passed to some unmanaged function and unmanaged function reads the value of array and does some changes. If the array is not pinned, changed values would not be able to be written back as pointer to array had been moved by GC.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is useful in questions context, but in managed scenario you could use [Marshall](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asx0thw2) class to allocate memory, move a structure to allocated memory and get a pointer back. This structure wouldn't be moved around by gc. Later on you could retrieve the structure from allocated memory using the pointer from before.